# about dll in .net

Tags: asp.net, dll

how to set the same dll for the typed dataset and untyped dataset using .net. in my program am writing the data set through coding in one page. am using connection string like this "server=10.103.200.142;User Id=root;password=test123;Persist Security Info=True;database=ezdatabase" in the same project in another page am creating dataset using wizards. Here also am using the same connection string . when i run this project am getting error. how do solve this? am getting error?

```
error
-----
  The type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand' exists in both  'c:\Users\Bharathiraja.m\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\rbuzz_test\d83db07e\8aa569c6\assembly\dl3\64f6c429\004e2a48_7b32cc01\MySql.Data.DLL' and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_6.3.6.0__c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll'                c:\Users\Bharathiraja.m\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\rbuzz_test\d83db07e\8aa569c6\App_Code.jla9qgxc.1.cs   7993       

web.config contains the following connection string
---------------------------------------------------
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ezdatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="server=10.103.200.192;User Id=user;password=pwd;Persist Security Info=True;database=ezdatabase" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
<add name="green" connectionString="server=10.103.200.192;User Id=user;database=ezdatabase; password= pwd " providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after emptying your `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder at `c:\Users\Bharathiraja.m\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`

Update: Check your `web.config` file to see if you have more than one reference to `MySql.Data.DLL`.

Comment: i tried . but i don't have folder named AppData under Bharathiraja.m

Comment: It's a hidden folder. Try going to Start Menu > Run, typing `c:\Users\Bharathiraja.m\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\` and press OK.

Comment: i tried .but that content under that particular folder automatically recreated after i run that programme

Comment: Yes, the content is recreated and that is normal. Did it solve your problem though?

Comment: Can you post your web.config file in your question? This is to check if you have multiple references to the same DLL there.

Comment: This is not a connection string problem. Check to see if you have more than one reference to MySql.Data.DLL in your web.config.

Comment: Open the file and see if there are two entries. Keep the one you need and delete the duplicate.